# Element Clickable in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to click on Calendar but everytime I try to click on the calendar the error pop up as "element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (293, 1317)

```
<input type="text" name="form_fields[travel_comp_date]" id="form-field-travel_comp_date"
class="elementor-field elementor-size-sm elementor-field-textual elementor-date-field
flatpickr-input" placeholder="Date of travel"
pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" readonly="readonly">
```

Here's my code:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(5));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//input[@name='form_fields[travel_comp_date]']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='form_fields[travel_comp_date]']")).click();
```

Can someone please help me correcting this.

Comment: Without seeing that page itself and all your code flow before the piece you shared we can't know what happens there

Comment: I'm working on this "https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companion/" there is a calendar in the page itself.  I'm trying to click on that but unable to as selenium is throwing error.

Comment: OK. What do you do after opening that page before trying to click that element?

Comment: Nothing, I just search for the element by using driver.findelement and then try to click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following code with explicit wait and let me know if it works for you:

```
enter code here
driver.get("https://www.path2usa.com/travel-companion/");
WebElement dateTravel =  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='form-field- 
travel_comp_date']"));
driver.manage().window().maximize();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,1000)");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 
Duration.ofSeconds(5));
js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", dateTravel);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(dateTravel));
if(dateTravel.isDisplayed()) 
  {
    js.executeScript("document.getElementById('form-field- 
travel_comp_date').value='12/20/2023'");
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The element you are trying to access is out of the initially presented view port.
In order to click it you first need to scroll the page to bring that element into the visible view port and only after that you will be able to click on it.
Please try this:

```java
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)");
```

Or this

```java
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,600)");
```

After that try performing your code

Comment: It is still not working. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Does my code perform scrolling and the element becomes actually visible before you clicking on it?

Comment: after the scrolling try adding some sleep of maybe a second before performing the click. let me know if that helped

Comment: Great! I'm happy I could help you :)

Comment: The above script worked with Thread.sleep but I'm trying to get it work through explicit wait. It is not working through explicit wait. Could you please let me know if it will work through explictit wati or not. If yes then how should I approach.

Comment: I tried to do that with explicit wait but it didn't work for me. Maybe if I had more time I would get better solution but I'm sorry, I have to work...

Comment: Okay.
If you have time then please check if it can workout with explicit wait.

Comment: Sure, but I can't promise. Maybe tomorrow.

Comment: It's okay.
Please take your time. I have been trying to do it for so long time but couldn't figure it out.